# Django 1.7 migration error

Tags: django, django-1.7, django-migrations

I changed a field from CharField to ForeignKey on a Model called Availability, when I am trying to migrate I keep getting the error below:

```
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field reservation.Availability.location: useraccount.Location
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

Thanks

--------------UPDATED CODE--------------

App: reservation

```
from useraccount.models import Location

class Availability(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
```

App: useraccount

```
class Location(models.Model):
    town = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.town + ', ' + self.county
```

Stacktrace

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
notification.NoticeSetting.send: (1_6.W002) BooleanField does not have a default value.
    HINT: Django 1.6 changed the default value of BooleanField from False to None. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield for more information.
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: reservation
Running migrations:
  Applying reservation.0010_auto_20141210_0357...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chirdeeptomar/envs/mydocbook/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 148, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: 'useraccount'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Did you run makemigrations already?

Comment: Yes, when I added Location to useraccount App, that migration is applied. I also have a Location foreign key to models in useraccount app and that migrated successfully. Order of applied migrations seems to be correct.

Comment: Full traceback please

Comment: Did you do both makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: Yeah, useraccount app is migrated except the last one.

Comment: If the delete the sqlite file and do a syncdb, I am getting django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: useraccount_location

Comment: Are you at the latest django version? I can find several posts with simmilar context but they seem to be solved after upgrading. [1](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23182), [2](https://github.com/amarsahinovic/django-migrations-bug-example), [3](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/tQQhTWWwhuQ).

Comment: You can also check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036336/operationalerror-no-such-table-on-initial-syncdb).

Comment: I just deleted the db and re-created the migrations...everything worked.

Comment: I know, it sounds like my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

What follows is a hack which is so easy and so nasty to apply **while developing** or even better while **learning** other parts of django and you just need a quick solution to get the work done ... in other words, a sin ... like bitter chocolate.

First of all, I keep my database data in a json file in case I need to rebuild it:

```
./manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes  --exclude reversion --exclude admin.LogEntry --indent 2 > db.json
```

When I change something in my models and I see that migrations start throwing errors, I try deleting everything regarding the application under consideration from the database (or -even better- the whole database) and then I rebuild it:

```
$./manage.py migrate <myapp1> zero #No need for this if the whole database is destroyed
$rm -Rf <myapp(s/1)>/migrations/*
$./manage.py makemigrations <myapp1>( <myapp2> ... <myappN>)
$./manage.py migrate <myapp(s/1)>
$./manage.py loaddata ...
```

This is most of the times faster than debugging the error. Sometimes, however, causes more problems than it is supposed to solve. This is when the database json file comes handy.

A pittiful solution but this is my revenge when all those details make me very angry and I enjoy it.

Comment: Very bad and ugly way btw, i do not recommend this way just because of one column migration

Comment: Yes, it is a hack. Ugly and sinful but most of the times I make changes I am already frustrated and I cannot bear more issues. I just want the changes to take place. I apologise again since it is a kind of canibalistic solution which -however- works both ways: The django way and my personal "issues" way.

Comment: If you have big db with live data used by millions of users per second, then your hack should not be used

Comment: Indeed, apply it only while developing. This is clear.

Comment: we effectively do something similar here, and I would still like a better way to deal with remaking migrations. :-/